# Kubernetes Hostpath External Provisioner - PVC Pending

Tags: dynamic, kubernetes, provisioning

I have set up a single node K8S cluster using kubeadm by following the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/):

The cluster is up and all system pods are running fine:

```
[root@umeshworkstation hostpath-provisioner]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-etcd-n988r                           1/1       Running   10         6h
calico-node-n1wmk                           2/2       Running   10         6h
calico-policy-controller-1777954159-bd8rn   1/1       Running   0          6h
etcd-umeshworkstation                       1/1       Running   1          6h
kube-apiserver-umeshworkstation             1/1       Running   1          6h
kube-controller-manager-umeshworkstation    1/1       Running   1          6h
kube-dns-3913472980-2ptjj                   0/3       Pending   0          6h
kube-proxy-1d84l                            1/1       Running   1          6h
kube-scheduler-umeshworkstation             1/1       Running   1          6h
```

I then downloaded Hostpath external provisioner code from [kubernetes-incubator](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/docs/demo/hostpath-provisioner) and built it locally on the same node. The docker image for provisioner built got successfully and I could even instantiate the provisioner pod using pod.yaml from same location. The pod is running fine:

```
[root@umeshworkstation hostpath-provisioner]# kubectl describe pod hostpath-provisioner
Name:           hostpath-provisioner
Namespace:      default
Node:           umeshworkstation/172.17.24.123
Start Time:     Tue, 09 May 2017 23:44:41 -0400
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             192.168.8.65
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  hostpath-provisioner:
    Container ID:       docker://c600cfa7a2f5f958ad24e83372a1276a91b41cb67773b9605af4a0ae021ec914
    Image:              hostpath-provisioner:latest
    Image ID:           docker://sha256:f6def41ba7c096701c65bf0c0aba6ff31e030573e1a900e378432491ecc5c556
    Port:
    State:              Running
      Started:          Tue, 09 May 2017 23:44:45 -0400
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment:
      NODE_NAME:         (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /tmp/hostpath-provisioner from pv-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7wwvj (ro)
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Initialized   True
  Ready         True
  PodScheduled  True
Volumes:
  pv-volume:
    Type:       HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:       /tmp/hostpath-provisioner
  default-token-7wwvj:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-7wwvj
    Optional:   false
QoS Class:      BestEffort
Node-Selectors: <none>
Tolerations:    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady=:Exists:NoExecute for 300s
                node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable=:Exists:NoExecute for 300s
Events:         <none>
```

I then created the storage class as per the instructions of project home, and storage class is created fine:

```
[root@umeshworkstation hostpath-provisioner]# kubectl describe sc example-hostpath
Name:           example-hostpath
IsDefaultClass: No
Annotations:    <none>
Provisioner:    example.com/hostpath
Parameters:     <none>
Events:         <none>
```

The next step was to create a PVC using claim.yaml from same location, but PVC is remaining in Pending state, and describe shows its not able to locate the provisioner example.com/hostpath:

```
[root@umeshworkstation hostpath-provisioner]# kubectl describe pvc
Name:           hostpath
Namespace:      default
StorageClass:   example-hostpath
Status:         Pending
Volume:
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class=example-hostpath
                volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner=example.com/hostpath
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                            SubObjectPath   Type            Reason                  Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                            -------------   --------        ------                  -------
  2h            11s             874     persistentvolume-controller                     Normal          ExternalProvisioning    cannot find provisioner "example.com/hostpath", expecting that a volume for the claim is provisioned either manually or via external software
```

The PVC has remained forever in Pending state because of this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: BTW, I observed `kube-dns` system pod was in pending state due to insufficient CPU resource. I added more cpu and now the `kube-dns` system pod is running fine, but the PVC continues to be in Pending state for same reason as before.

Comment: Can you post the logs from the hostpath-provisioner pod

Comment: I have the below logs repeated for provisioner pod:

Comment: `E0511 10:46:32.442032       1 reflector.go:201] hostpath-provisioner/vendor/github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/lib/controller/controller.go:270: Failed to list *v1.StorageClass: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list storageclasses.storage.k8s.io at the cluster scope. (get storageclasses.storage.k8s.io)'

Comment: `E0511 10:46:32.442145       1 reflector.go:201] hostpath-provisioner/vendor/github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/lib/controller/controller.go:294: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list persistentvolumeclaims at the cluster scope. (get persistentvolumeclaims)`

Comment: `E0511 10:46:32.443130       1 reflector.go:201] hostpath-provisioner/vendor/github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/lib/controller/controller.go:295: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list persistentvolumes at the cluster scope. (get persistentvolumes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue.. Thanks @jaxxstorm for helping me move towards in the right direction.

When I inspected provisioner pod logs I could see that its unable to access the API server to list StorageClass, PVC or PVs as it was created with default service account, which does not have the privileges to access these APIs.

The solution was to create a separate service account, pod security policy, cluster role and cluster role binding, as explained for [NFS external provisioner here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/nfs/docs/authorization.md)

After this I could see my PVC getting binded to the volume and hostpath showing the mount

```
[root@umeshworkstation hostpath-provisioner]# kubectl get pvc
NAME       STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE
hostpath   Bound     pvc-8179c8d6-36db-11e7-9ed4-005056a21a50   1Mi        RWX           example-hostpath   1m

[root@umeshworkstation hostpath-provisioner]# ls /tmp/hostpath-provisioner/
pvc-8179c8d6-36db-11e7-9ed4-005056a21a50
```