# Kuberentes External provisioning wont create volume

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pvc

Hi there I followed this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/) back in march and got it up and running. I have been refreshing on the area and was doing it again... but now it no longer works. Is there any changes that have occurred to kubernetes that has changed in the mean time that caused this issue?

Here is the error code in PVC:
[image: Error code]

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888338/kubernetes-hostpath-external-provisioner-pvc-pending) addresses this by pointing to another link, but this link isnt working any more!

I am running my kubernetes cluster on Minikube version v1.17.1

Answer (score 1):

Check your `kubectl client` version is compatible with the `minikube` version, in case needs, do upgrade the components. Also, check PV status on your system and and try defining the storage class, `storageClassName: standard` in your pv definition as below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgresql-storage
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  hostPath:
      path: /data/postgresql/
```